# replace with for in Foxpro

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am reverse engineering a program made in FoxPro.

**I know nothing of FoxPro**, fortunately the program is simple and more or less I could understand all processes

I have this, in the source code

```
Select 1
SET RELATION TO GROUP_T+POL INTO BASE2
REPLACE MARK_T WITH BASE2->STATUS FOR GROUP_T+POL=BASE2->GROUP_T+POL
REPLACE LAPSE2 WITH BASE2->LAPSE FOR GROUP_T+POL=BASE2->GROUP_T+POL
REPLACE STATUS2 WITH BASE2->STATUS FOR GROUP_T+POL=BASE2->GROUP_T+POL
REPLACE DATPAHAS2 WITH BASE2->DATPAHAS FOR GROUP_T+POL=BASE2->GROUP_T+POL
CLOSE DATABASES
```

I need to know from where the variable `LAPSE2` this is used later.

But i don´t know as calculated

**What does this mean?**

```
REPLACE LAPSE2 WITH BASE2->LAPSE FOR GROUP_T+POL=BASE2->GROUP_T+POL
```

This is the only line that appears before use later in a condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fragment that you showed, the value of each `LAPSE2` in the current table is replaced with the value of the `LAPSE` field of the first matching record in `BASE2`, based on the index currently set in that table.

The `FOR` clause restricts this to records that do have matching records in `BASE2`; unmatched records are skipped (remain unchanged). Without this filter the new value for `LAPSE2` would be an empty value ('', .f., 0, ...) when there is no matching record.

Note: a `REPLACE` without any `FOR` or `WHILE` would affect only a single record, since the absence of a scope clause implies `NEXT 1` (another way of looking at it would be that `FOR` sort of implies `ALL` and `WHILE` sort of implies `REST`).

The `SET RELATION` statement at the beginning of the code fragment causes Fox to perform a seek in the `BASE2` table with the result of evaluating the expression `GROUP_T+POL` whenever the record pointer changes. Put differently: whenever the record pointer is moved in the master table, the record pointer in the child table(s) is moved to the first matching record (if any) or to EOF if there are no matches.

Hence the combination of `SET RELATION` with `REPLACE ... FOR <key match>` is similar to

```
replace LAPSE2 with Base2.LAPSE for seek(GROUP_T + POL, [Base2])
```

Note: this statement is only intended to illustrate what happens; it should never be used in actual code because it is fraught with problems and bugs.